# Add Key to appsettings in web.config shows An error occurred loading a configuration file: Access to the path 'c:\inetpub\vobv5_zi.tmp' is denied

Tags: c#, vb.net, web-config, appsettings

I am trying to add appsettings in web.config which is in C://inetpub  folder.
Am getting error An error occurred loading a configuration file: Access to the path 'c:\inetpub\vobv5_zi.tmp' is denied. (c:\inetpub\web.config.config)

Here is my code

in Vb

```
Dim config As Configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration("c:\inetpub\" & sServer & "\web.config")
        config.AppSettings.Settings.Add(sSearch, "C:\Attachments\")
        config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified)
        ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings")
```

in C#

```
   var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration("c:\\inetpub\\web.config");
        config.AppSettings.Settings.Add("OS", "Linux");
        config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
```

I tried in both VB and C# .
when my web.config is with in project it is adding appsettings while my web.config is in inetpub it is throwing error
An error occurred loading a configuration file: Access to the path 'c:\inetpub\yzb2crt2.tmp' is denied.

Answer (score 0):

The user that is running the code (not quite clear *how* you are running the code) needs to have write permissions on the file.

Seems pretty clear so perhaps there is more information you might need to give us?

Comment: Where is this code been called from? What user did you give perms to? Giving perms to the web.config file may not be enough (as it appears to be writing to a tmp file first). if you are running locally try add "Everyone" to full control on the folder (and *immediately* remove after testing) and if that works, try the User running the code (and remove).

Comment: when i run my visual studio 2012 in run as administrator mode am not getting any error ..but app key is not adding in appsettings

Comment: ya i added Everyone and starting my visual studio in run as admin mode am not getting any error but appsettings is not adding

Comment: protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration("c:\\inetpub\\web.config");
            config.AppSettings.Settings.Add("OS", "Linux");
            config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Full);

            ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
        }

Comment: am testing in my page load @Mark ...can u please look at this

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got the solution for this

```
  var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load("c:\\inetpub\\web2.config");

        var nodeRegion = xmlDoc.CreateElement("add");
        nodeRegion.SetAttribute("key", "Region");
        nodeRegion.SetAttribute("value", "Canterbury");

        xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//appSettings").AppendChild(nodeRegion);
        xmlDoc.Save("c:\\inetpub\\web2.config");

        ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
```

by this am adding appsettings in web.config file in inetpub.